# How to create a hotkey for desktop icon using Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup, hotkeys, shortcut-file

How do I create a shortcut hotkey for an icon in Inno Setup?

The website says add this:

> HotKey: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

Does anyone have sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HotKey`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_iconssection.htm#HotKey) is an optional parameter for [`[Icons]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_iconssection.htm) section entries, so simply add it to your icon entry e.g. this way:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MYPROG.EXE"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    HotKey: "ctrl+alt+k"
```

Comment: Any ideas i can assign an icon to my application also.. I just noticed that my shortcut doesnt show the icon?

Comment: Assuming you're developing your application in Visual Studio (according to your previous C# questions), icon specified [`this way`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx) should be the one taken for the shortcut. But if you'd like to specify an icon different from the application one, you could do it in the `IconFilename` parameter.